# Edit dynamically created li elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the user to be able to edit dynamically created list items that are input into a ul by the user.

I have no problem changing other items but the fact that the li items don't exist until input by the user is stumping me.  I don't have any id's or classes to select to add a dblclick event to and selecting the child elements of all ul doesn't seem to work.

In short I just want to either:

- click an icon on each list item that will allow me to edit the text
  or
- just double click the text which will allow me to edit it. (dblclick because the items are already draggable.)

I've tried a number of things but I'm not sure where to start now.
Thanks!

```html
<div id="listWrapper" class="row">
  <div id="dayInfo" class="container col-8">
    <div class="card">
      <img id="mondayImg" class="card-img-top">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 id="title" class="card-title">My Coding To-Do List</h3>
        <div id="subTitle" class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h5>Still to do</h5>
            <button id="allFinished" class="btn btn-success">Move all to finished</button>
            <hr>
            <ul class="toBeSaved edit" id="stillToDo">
            </ul>
            <!-- <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>  -->
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <h5>In Progress</h5>
            <button id="allFinished2" class="btn btn-success">Move all to finished</button>
            <hr>
            <ul class="toBeSaved edit" id="inProgress">
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <h5>Finished</h5>
            <button id="removeFinished" class="btn btn-danger">Remove finished</button>
            <hr>
            <ul class="toBeSaved edit" id="finished">
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="newItemWrapper">
          <input id="newItem" placeholder="Add a new item">
          <br>
          <h6 id="newItemBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Add new item</h6>
          <br>
          <h6 id="save" class="btn btn-success">Save</h6>
          <h6 id="clear" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</h6>
          <p class="card-text"><small id="lastUpdated" class="text-muted toBeSaved">Last updated </small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#newItem").focus();
  //Adding a new items when click or enter pressed//
  function addNewItem() {
    let newInput = $("#newItem").val();
    $("#stillToDo").append("<li>" + newInput + "</li>");
    $("#newItem").val("");
    $("#lastUpdated").text("Last updated " + Date());
  };

  $("#newItemBtn").click(addNewItem);

  $("#newItem").keypress(function(e) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      addNewItem();
    }
  });

  //Moving list itmes and removing list items//
  $("#allFinished").click(function() {
    $("#finished").append($("#stillToDo li"))
  });

  $("#allFinished2").click(function() {
    $("#finished").append($("#inProgress li"))
  });

  $("#removeFinished").click(function() {
    $("#finished li").remove();
  });

  //So you can drag items across to another list
  $("#stillToDo").sortable({
    connectWith: "#finished, #inProgress"
  });

  $("#inProgress").sortable({
    connectWith: "#finished, #stillToDo"
  })

  $("#finished").sortable({
    connectWith: "#stillToDo, #inProgress"
  });

  //THIS IS SAVING LIST INFO and LAST UPDATED IN THE HTML 5 LOCAL STORAGE//
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save").click(function(e) { //Clicking the "save button"//
      e.preventDefault();

      var everything = [];
      $(".toBeSaved").each(function() {
        everything.push(this.innerHTML);
      })
      localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(everything));
    });

    //RETREIVEING LISTS AND "UPDATED ON" FROM LOCAL STORAGE//
    function loadEverything() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('list')) {
        var everything = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'));
        $(".toBeSaved").each(function(i) {
          this.innerHTML = everything[i];
        })
      }
    }
    loadEverything(); //<--This is calling the above function, without this nothing happens//

    $("#clear").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      localStorage.clear();
      location.reload();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to edit text is to replace the text with an `input` element with it's value set to the text as follows:

```
//Edit added li elements
$(document).on('dblclick', 'ul.toBeSaved.edit li', function() {
    let inEdit = $('<input/>');
    let toEdit = $(this);
    toEdit.html( inEdit.val( toEdit.text() ) );
    inEdit.focus().select();
});

$(document).on('focusout keypress', 'ul.toBeSaved.edit li input', function(e) {
    if( e.which === 13 || e.type === 'focusout') {
        let val = $(this).val();
        $(this).closest('li').text( val );
    }
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
        $(function() {

            $("#newItem").focus();

            //Adding a new items when click or enter pressed//

            function addNewItem() {
                let newInput = $("#newItem").val();


                $("#stillToDo").append("<li>" + newInput + "</li>");
                $("#newItem").val("");
                $("#lastUpdated").text("Last updated " + Date());
            };


            $("#newItemBtn").click(addNewItem);

            $("#newItem").keypress(function(e) {
                if (event.which == 13) {
                    addNewItem();

                }
            });
            //End of adding a new items when click or enter pressed//


            //Moving list itmes and removing list items//
            $("#allFinished").click(function() {
                $("#finished").append($("#stillToDo li"))
            });

            $("#allFinished2").click(function() {
                $("#finished").append($("#inProgress li"))
            });

            $("#removeFinished").click(function() {
                $("#finished li").remove();
            });
            //End of Moving list itmes and removing list items//




            //So you can drag items across to another list
            $("#stillToDo").sortable({
                connectWith: "#finished, #inProgress"
            });

            $("#inProgress").sortable({
                connectWith: "#finished, #stillToDo"
            })

            $("#finished").sortable({
                connectWith: "#stillToDo, #inProgress"
            });


            //THIS IS SAVING LIST INFO and LAST UPDATED IN THE HTML 5 LOCAL STORAGE//
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#save").click(function(e) { //Clicking the "save button"//
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var everything = [];
                    $(".toBeSaved").each(function() {
                        everything.push(this.innerHTML);
                    })
                    localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(everything));

                });
                //\\END OF THIS IS SAVING LIST INFO and "UPDATED ON" IN THE BROWSER'S LOCAL STORAGE//

                //RETREIVEING LISTS AND "UPDATED ON" FROM LOCAL STORAGE//
                function loadEverything() {
                    if (localStorage.getItem('list')) {
                        var everything = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'));
                        $(".toBeSaved").each(function(i) {
                            this.innerHTML = everything[i];
                        })
                    }
                }
                loadEverything(); //<--This is calling the above function, without this nothing happens//
                //END OF RETREIVEING LISTS AND "UPDATED ON" FROM LOCAL STORAGE//


                $("#clear").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    localStorage.clear();
                    location.reload();
                });


            });
            
            //Edit added li elements
            $(document).on('dblclick', 'ul.toBeSaved.edit li', function() {
                let inEdit = $('<input/>');
                let toEdit = $(this);
                toEdit.html( inEdit.val( toEdit.text() ) );
                inEdit.focus().select();
            });
 
            $(document).on('focusout keypress', 'ul.toBeSaved.edit li input', function(e) {
                if( e.which === 13 || e.type === 'focusout') {
                    let val = $(this).val();
                    $(this).closest('li').text( val );
                }
            });


        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable-min.js" integrity="sha512-9pm50HHbDIEyz2RV/g2tn1ZbBdiTlgV7FwcQhIhvykX6qbQitydd6rF19iLmOqmJVUYq90VL2HiIUHjUMQA5fw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div id="listWrapper" class="row">
        <div id="dayInfo" class="container col-8">

            <div class="card">
                <img id="mondayImg" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">

                    <h3 id="title" class="card-title">My Coding To-Do List</h3>

                    <div id="subTitle" class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <h5>Still to do</h5>
                            <button id="allFinished" class="btn btn-success">Move all to finished</button>
                            <hr>
                            <ul class="toBeSaved edit" id="stillToDo">
                            </ul>
                            <!-- <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>  -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col">
                            <h5>In Progress</h5>
                            <button id="allFinished2" class="btn btn-success">Move all to finished</button>
                            <hr>
                            <ul class="toBeSaved edit" id="inProgress">
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col">
                            <h5>Finished</h5>
                            <button id="removeFinished" class="btn btn-danger">Remove finished</button>
                            <hr>
                            <ul class="toBeSaved edit" id="finished">
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="newItemWrapper">
                        <input id="newItem" placeholder="Add a new item">
                        <br>
                        <h6 id="newItemBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Add new item</h6>
                        <br>
                        <h6 id="save" class="btn btn-success">Save</h6>
                        <h6 id="clear" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</h6>
                        <p class="card-text"><small id="lastUpdated" class="text-muted toBeSaved">Last updated </small></p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I. Love. You.   I sort of figured there needed to be variables in there somewhere but was never going to work that out!  I was going for the contenteditable approach.  Thank you!